# filter design for ECG

Tags: noise, filter-design, lowpass-filter, ecg

I would like to ask how to design a digital filter to remove $50$ Hz interference on an ECG signal. Do I need to use notch filter? 
Thanks.

Comment: http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1542-474X.2009.00328.x/abstract;jsessionid=E1B2F58BB7E533457878702593E9CF09.f02t01 I think that this article may be helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will need to make a 50Hz notch filter.

I would suggest you to look at [this post](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/26688/47790).

If you tell what type of program you use (Python, R, etc) I could try to provide you some code aswell.

Answer (score 1):

One paper that everybody starts with for ECG is Pan and Tompkins[1]. Wikipedia page is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pan%E2%80%93Tompkins_algorithm). They use a low pass filter with cutoff frequency of 11Hz followed by a high pass filter with cutoff of 5 Hz. The lowpass will remove 50 Hz noise.

[1] Pan, Jiapu; Tompkins, Willis J. (March 1985). "A Real-Time QRS Detection Algorithm". IEEE Transactions on Biomedical Engineering. BME-32 (3): 230–236.

The only thing to be careful with is initial conditions of the lowpass filter. You'll want to load x (1 to 12 or 0:11) with zeros and y(1:2 or 0:1) with zeros.