# Filter design with zero - pole placement method

Tags: filters, filter-design, homework, poles-zeros

I have some question for you about Filter design.

- Α. Calculate the transfer function in order to stop the frequency of $300\textrm{ Hz}$ for sampling frequency at $12\textrm{ kHz}$. Use the
  zero – pole placement method
- Β. Calculate the absolute value for the designed filter at $f_1=300\textrm{ Hz}$ and at $f_2=200\textrm{ Hz}$.

Can someone show me how can i solved this problem.

Comment: Yes it is homework, this is the last job it is not impossible and I have no idea how to take it.  just only zero-pole placement method. The letter B is another question of my homework. can you give me some tips how should i start this ?.

Comment: You have to design a notch filter with a notch frequency of 300 Hz. This means that the transfer function must have a zero at that frequency. [This answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/26690/4298) should be helpful.

Comment: Do you know the pole-zero placement method in filter design? Or better do you know the individual effects of a given pole or zero on the frequency response of a (stable) filter ?

Comment: No i didnt know.

Comment: I just try to solved this problem with your link but i don't think so it is correct. which value i have to put on  my "r" value ?   w = 2 * Pi * f0 / fs         and then i have  w0 right and what nex i just have to calculate r value right ? but how ?

Answer (score 10):

Here let me show you a simple procedure very similar to pole zero placement which will be helpful for your notch filter design.

First, lets analyse the frequency response of a single zero and let 
$$ H(z) = 1 - b z^{-1} $$
be a first order system with a single zero at $z = b$ where $b$ is a **complex** constant with a radius $r$ and phase angle $\phi$ radians; i.e.,
$$ b = r e^{j\phi} $$

Lets see this zero on the z-plane and the corresponding frequency response magnitude for the values of $r = 0.9$ and $\phi = \pi/4$ radians:
[image]

Note that since there is a single zero, this is a non-symmetric frequency response (due to a complex impulse response $h[n]$). To get rid of this non-symmetric frequency response, we shall force the impulse response to be **real** and the way to achieve this is to add a second zero at the **complex-conjugate** location resulting in the filter:
$$ H_{az}(z) = (1 - bz^{-1})(1 - b^{*} z^{-1}) $$ 
as the second figure shows:

[image]

Now we have a pair of **complex-conjugate** zeros, whose frequency response is conjugate symmetric (and therefore the magnitude response is even symmetric as displayed)

next, we display the same figures, for a pair of complex-conjugate **poles** with a radius of $r=0.85$ and the same angle $\phi = \pi/4$ radians:
$$ H_{ap}(z) = \frac{1}{(1 - az^{-1})(1 - a^{*} z^{-1})} $$

[image]

So far we have displayed the pole-zero locations and corresponding frequency responses for individual pairs of poles and zeros at the same frequency. Lets combine them into a single filter and display the result:
$$ H(z) = \frac{(1 - bz^{-1})(1 - b^{*} z^{-1})}{(1 - az^{-1})(1 - a^{*} z^{-1})} $$ 
[image]

Nice! We have reached a system whose frequency response now resembles that of a notch, but a weak one? The solution comes by recognizing that we should better **put the zero** on the **unit circle** (i.e., set its radius $r=1$) for an infinetely deep nulling at that frequency; 
[image]

Now this system is what can be called as a 2nd order notch filter with a pole radius of $r=0.85$ and radian frequency of $\omega = \pi/4$ radians per sample. This is a quite satisfactory notch filter.

Finally lets display a much **sharper** notch by moving the pole closer to the zero (closer to the unit circle) by setting its radius to $r = 0.99$. But note that it's very dangerous for a pole to wander about unit circle, as it can easily fall over it, thereby making the system **unstable**...
[image]

For your convenience, choose the pole radius between 0.9 and 0.99 depending on your numerical accuracy and how sharp a notch you need. And adjust the frequency of the pole-zero pair according to which frequency you want to null.