# I am stuck on a problem that only has a center frequency of $\pi/2$ for an IIR filter pole-zero plot of this using 2 poles and 4 zeros

Tags: filters, infinite-impulse-response

Using a pole zero placement method, design an infinite impulse response band-pass filter with center frequency of $\pi/2$ radians per second. Hint: Use two poles and four zeros.

Comment: 1 - What have you tried so far?
2 - What is the effect of a pole on the frequency response? 
3 - What is the effect of a zero on the frequency response?

Comment: Try this? https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/41642/filter-design-with-zero-pole-placement-method

Comment: Welcome to SE.SP!  This question looks like a homework question, and the linked-to "duplicate" looks like it will help you answer it.  If you have a homework question, we will answer it here, but only if you include your working to date and an attempt to explain why you can't get any further.  Please [edit your question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/posts/66664/edit) to add these details and I'll reopen the question.