# Is Kaiser-Bessel filter good for notch filtering with time-sensitive data?

Tags: filters, filter-design, time-domain

I'm working with ECG signal processing and want to implement digital notch filter. Would Kaiser-Bessel filter be optimal for signals sensitive to time domain disruptions or should I use different filter?

Comment: You're probably thinking in terms of group delay, but you need filtering, too, and the frequency response will be awful. Better use other tried and tested techniques.

Comment: If you want to implement a digital notch filter, this implies that your interference is periodic in time (such as 50 Hz line noise?). There are several other posts here details such notch filter implementations such as: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/31028/transfer-function-of-second-order-notch-filter/31030#31030 and https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/63089/is-a-notch-filter-for-50-hz-without-delay-possible/63090#63090