Removing low frequency hum from signal in real-time
I am getting a 0.3Hz, 30uV hum on a 2.5V signal from an ADC reading a temperature sensor (sampled at 10sps). I need to attenuate this hum to < 20uV in order to keep the last digit of the temperature reading from flipping. This is a 'real-time' (max. response time is 0.5s) application so I am looking for a predictive filtering method.
The hum varies in amplitude and frequency by +/- 5% over the span of several minutes.
Whatever happens in the target 20uV range doesn't matter as long as it doesn't change the mean. Also, these experiments run over several days so rounding errors could become an issue (although there is enough compute power to work with high precision floating point libraries).
My current approach:

Get hum frequency from DFT
Setup (9 samples) moving average on the signal to remove other noise
Track the hum with running averages on frequency and amplitude
Every half-period, calculate f and magnitude for attenuation sine
Shift sine to account for the moving average and to oppose the original hum
Add to original signal

The result is okay, it never spikes outside the original envelope and generally stays in the 20uV range. However, I'm convinced there are more efficient/simpler/less hacky ways of accomplishing this. I've been looking into continuously correlating the last few samples with the best wavelet match and using that instead but haven't gone down that path yet.
I'm not a DSP engineer (although I find the area fascinating) so I'm looking for guidance on a more efficient and standardized approach.
Additonal info: The ADC is an ADS1256 (24 bits, ENOB 24.2 bits, 22 noise free bits at full scale / 10 SPS). I suspect the hum is not caused by the ADC itself but by the supplied Vref, hopefully this can be fixed with the next test setup revision.
Further clarification: So far, the observed min/max frequencies of the hum are 0.27 / 0.34 Hz. Fluctuations from one period to the next are up to +/- 0.005 Hz.

first question: what's the number of bits, and the effective number of bits (ENOB) of your ADC? (or its spurious-free dynamic range)? Also: you have a mathematical hard problem, because 0.5 s is smaller than 1/(0.3 Hz). So, if anything about your 0.3 Hz changes during observation, or you have less than an initial 1/(0.3 Hz) to "lock onto" your hum, you're essentially hosed.

@MarcusMüller Thank you, updated the question. Yes, I'm aware the timing is tight and there are alerts in place tshould it get out of sync. It's a stop-gap fix until we can get rid of the hum at the source

Have you seen this solution to implement a notch filter? https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/31030/21048

@DanBoschen: that's a fixed-frequency notch filter.  Probably won't help in this case.

@TimWescott do you know that this 0.3 Hz sinusoidal component is not fixed in frequency?

Ah if it isn’t fixed that link I sent it not a good solution. This one might work well be since it will track the frequency of the tone: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/63090/21048

@robertbristow-johnson: the question says the hum varies in amplitude and frequency.  So -- to the extent I believe the OP, yes.

Oh.  I missed that.  I thought it was just 0.3 Hz.  Seems to me that you just gotta do a good DC blocking filter that has an upper limit on the stopband around DC.

@DanBoschen Thank you for the suggestion! I will study it and evaluate it for my purpose

The general class of system that you've designed is an adaptive filter.  There should be extensive literature on adaptive notch filtering out there -- I suggest you study up and find the best intersection between what you have, what you need, and what you know how to implement.
If I were going to do this without doing a literature search first, I'd compare the performance of the typical gradient-descent notch filter (which will be easier to understand and code, but slower to respond to frequency changes) vs. an extended Kalman filter (which will be harder to understand and code, but should respond faster to frequency changes).
The gradient descent filter could be an IIR or FIR filter -- check the literature, there should be examples of both.
The Kalman filter would start with a model that has two states for the hum itself, plus one for the frequency -- so the system would be $y = f(\mathbf x, u)$ where
$$\mathbf x_k = \begin{bmatrix}
\cos \omega & \sin \omega & 0 \\
-\sin \omega & \cos \omega & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \omega
\end{bmatrix} x_{k-1} + 
\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0
\end{bmatrix} u_k
\tag 1$$
and
$$y_k = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \tag 2$$
Constructed correctly, the resulting filter would track $\omega$ and the signal itself.  $y_k$ would be the estimate of the hum signal, so you'd just subtract it out of your raw signal to get your desired one.

Note that if this is really a one-off experiment, and not a production system where long-term code robustness or hardware costs are the highest priority, you're probably fine doing what you're doing.  If you need to chance that last fractional bit of precision, or if you're going to build 1000 of these using the cheapest available processor -- go do a literature search, and consider using my solution.

Thank you for clarifying what I'm looking for and for suggesting the EKF (even with an initial state). The more I'm learning about it the more I understand how elegant it is -- it might even give us a smooth derivative. I will certainly try to implement this solution and report back
