# IIR Cascaded Filter Response, Unexpected Results

Tags: matlab, filter-design, digital-filters, biquad

I am attempting to understand how to manipulate portions of a cascaded series of biquad notch filters in a control system I am working with.

As part of determining the composite response of all the cascaded filters, I am starting with looking at the individual biquad filters. I have taken the existing control system coefficients that I have for the filters and have saved the various biquad filters in the Filter design tool. When I use the MATLAB/Simulink filter design tool, I obtain an unexpected response as well as an unstable root/pole plot. I have excerpted an image below of one of the filters from the control system.

[image]
The system sampling frequency is 10 khz. The Form is Direct Form II. The a0 coefficient is normalized to 1.

My specific questions are:

1. Is this response still consistent with a notch filter?
2. If this is still applicable as a notch filter, why would the filter start with a negative magnitude and then return to a positive magnitude? For context, I am used to the analog realm and a notch filter starting at 0 db and ending at 0db.
3. If I needed to attenuate a specific frequency as viewed from power spectra of the feedback in the control system, would it be appropriate to modify a particular notch filter of my cascaded series to focus in on that frequency or since they are cascaded, would I have to modify all terms slightly?

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: Look at the image you posted

"Stable : No"

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a simple sign error in the denominator. If you use a = [1 -1.866685 .91058], you get something that looks notch-like at around 380 Hz.

> The Form is Direct Form II

This is numerically the worst. Shouldn't matter here, but it's good practice to either stick with Direct Form I or Transposed Form II.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that your filter does not look like a notch at the moment. But the biggest issue is that it's unstable.

I recommend you check this thread on how to design an IIR notch filter

[Analytically designing a notch-filter for specified frequency 50 Hz](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/26688/analytically-designing-a-notch-filter-for-specified-frequency-50-hz)